# Storing a list of rng's in a std::array for multithreading

Tags: c++, random, c++11, decltype

I'd like to multithread my rng part of my code using C++11.

I create a bunch of RNG's like this:

```
typedef std::mt19937 mersenne_twister;
typedef std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unidist;

// 8 rng engines with 8 consecutive seeds
const size_t Nrng = 8;
const array<uint32_t,Nrng> seed_values = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
array<mersenne_twister,Nrng> engines;
const array<unidist,Nrng> distributions; // default constructor is for [0,1] interval

const array<????,Nrng> rngs; // What type do I put here?

for( size_t i=0; i<Nrng; ++i )
    engines[i].seed(seed_values[i]);
    rngs[i] = std::bind(distributions[i], engines[i]);
```

With the idea I can later pass each of the RNG objects to a seperate `std::thread` that fills another `array` with some form of random numbers using the supplied generator. I don't know what type I need to use for the rng `array`. I know how to create one rng, like so:

```
auto rng = std::bind(unidist, generator);
```

but I need to explicitely have a (`decltype`d?) type for the `array`.

Comment: Do you really need to store the distributions? They're just little caller adapters with no state. You might as well just have a *global* `unidist`, and use `unidist(rngs[i])` where needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible type would be `std::function<double()>`, but note that this doesn't come free. The actual type of the result of `bind` is unknowable, and so you cannot just make a container with element type `decltype(std::bind(...))`, since the types are not guaranteed to be mutually convertible -- all you know is that they all convert to `function`.

If this is performance-critical, I suggest you profile and compare the cost of `std::function` to the direct use of `unidist(rngs[i])` in your target code. (The distribution is a stateless adapter that should be reentrant anyway, so you don't need to keep more than one copy of it.)

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. I'm going to make a global `unidist` variable and pass the `mersenne_twister` to my functions, generating random numbers by calling `unidist(engine)`.